# How to call a https rest service without client certificate

Tags: https, rest-client

I will have to consume a https rest service without sending the certificate, but my application is still trying to find path.

```
try
{
  HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(null, ResourceUtil.getEnvironmentMessage(URL), new sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler()).openConnection();
  connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
  connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
  connection.connect();
  String inputRequest = buildJsonRequest(request);

  connection.setDoOutput(true);
  OutputStream ucdlRequestStream = connection.getOutputStream();
  requestStream.write(inputRequest.getBytes());
  requestStream.flush();

  if (connection.getResponseCode() != 200)
  {
    throw new SystemException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + connection.getResponseCode());
  }

  BufferedReader responseReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((connection.getInputStream())));

  String output;
  LOGGER.info("Output from Server .... \n");
  while ((output = responseReader.readLine()) != null)
  {
    boolean hasActiveProducts = output.contains("ACTIVE");
    LOGGER.info(output);
  }
  connection.disconnect();
}
catch (IOException | EASystemException e)
{
  LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
  throw new SystemException(e.getMessage(), e);
}
LOGGER.info(String.valueOf(hasActiveProducts));
return hasActiveProducts;
```

Seeing below error:
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with a loads of googling, managed to find below.

```
try
{
  HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(null, url, new 
  sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler()).openConnection();  
  connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
  connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
  String inputRequest = buildRequest(object);
  
  TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager()
  {
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers()
    {
      return null;
    }

    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s)
    {
    }

    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s)
    {
    }
  }};

  // Install the all-trusting trust manager
  SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
  sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, null);
  connection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
  
  connection.setDoOutput(true);
  connection.setDoInput(true);
  OutputStream ucdlRequestStream = connection.getOutputStream();
  ucdlRequestStream.write(inputRequest.getBytes());
  ucdlRequestStream.flush();
  ucdlRequestStream.close();
  LOGGER.info(ucdlRequestStream.toString());
  LOGGER.info(connection.getOutputStream().toString());
  LOGGER.info(String.valueOf(connection.getResponseCode()));

  if (connection.getResponseCode() != 200)
  {
    throw new EASystemException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + connection.getResponseCode());
  }
 }
  catch (IOException | EASystemException e)
  {
    LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    throw new SystemException(e.getMessage(), e);
  }
```